deploying spring boot + postgres with docker composer causes JDBC ERROR
So, Im trying to deploy a project (so I can tag it, send to my repo and use it on a remote server with SSH), but i cant the springapp with postgresQL :/
This is my application properties:
spring.application.name=Arcade
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.devtools.restart.enabled=true
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/static/
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost/Arcade
spring.datasource.username= ***
spring.datasource.password= ***
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.boot.allow_jdbc_metadata_access=false
spring.sql.init.mode=never

And this is my docker-compose file:
services:
  springapp:
    build: .
    container_name: arcade-springapp
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://arcade-db:5432/arcade
    ports:
      - 8000:8080
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - arcade-db
      ##- hazelcast
      ##- hazelcast-mc
    networks:
      - backend

  arcade-db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: arcade-database
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER= ***
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD= ***
      - POSTGRES_DB=arcade
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data

    restart: always
    networks:
      - backend
volumes:
  pgdata:

networks:
  backend:

and finally, this is my dockerfile:
FROM openjdk:21

# Set working directory for runtime stage
WORKDIR /app
# Copy the application jar
COPY /target/*.jar /app/app.jar

# Expose the port where your Spring application serves static content (e.g., 8080)
EXPOSE 8080

# Set the command to run the application (replace with your actual entry point)
CMD ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]

If my application properties is "localhost/arcade", i use
mvn clean package
docker compose up --build

and it works like a charm
but if my application properties is "arcade-db:5432/arcade" and try using mvn clean package, I got the error:
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [Connection failed] [n/a]

and if its the "ip:5432/arcade", the error changes to:
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out

Theres another way of doing it? Or What am I missing?
Im using mvn clean package but should use another thing?
thanks!
I've already tried skipping maven tests, but it goes wrong too with database's gone.

The  environment: { SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: ... } overrides the application.properties spring.datasource.url=... setting.  The arcade-db host name is specific to the Compose setup, and overriding it in the docker-compose.yml file makes sense; you shouldn't need to rebuild your jar file to redeploy the application in different environments.  It seems like the setup with the files you show at the top of the question works; is there a specific problem you're running into?

So, if it always replaces one with the other, can I leave localhost there?

Well, it was a cache ERROR, just deleting "pgdata" folder and not rebuilding everytime worked. I think for now.
